# How to increase the download size of system data to more than 200 in Maximo Anywhere App

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Whenever we preview MaximoAnywhere app in the browser, we get the message "When running in a browser, a maximum of 200 records are downloaded per lookup."
Is there a way to increase the download size?.
I have maxdomains with size of 275, and running into problem because the data that I am looking for is not present in the jsonstore during the debugging.
I am using the clone of Maximo Anywhere Inspection app 7.5.2.1, Maximo 7.6, Chrome for preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the app.xml, you can add the debug="true" flag as shown below:

```
<!-- =================================== -->
<!-- WORK EXECUTION APPLICATION ARTIFACT -->
<!-- =================================== -->

<app blindQuerySupport="false" debug="false" id="WorkExecution" logLevel="2" requiredRole="ANYWHERE_TECHNICIAN" version="201506051458" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../build/app.xsd">
```

Please note, if there is too much data it will not all download as the JSONstore is limited in storage.

Hope this helps.

Thanks